# Professional Web Authoring / Design Software

Tags: gui, web

Can someone please recommend some professional website authoring design software which has a GUI and a live edit much the same was as DreamWeaver.

However, unlike DW I would like the ability to take the contents of a css file reference and insert this inline in my code (and vice versa).  I'd also like to be able to remove unused styles and do a global rename of styles.

I'm not too particular regarding graphic editing however I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks very much.

Comment: i can't believe this doesn't have an answer - same question here.